# CSS Positioning: A row of floating left, followed by a block underneath

Tags: css, css-float

I want a row of blocks from left to right, followed by a block underneath.

Here is a picture of what I would like to see rendered in the browser.
[image: Desired rendering of HTML]

I need to do all positioning by CSS, not by tables. Here is my HTML and my CSS...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head><link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css" /><head>

<body>

<form action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Field set A</legend>
    <label for="password">Password
      <input id="password" name="password" type="text" value="my password" />
    </label>            
  </fieldset>               
  <fieldset class="radio">
    <legend>Chaining mode</legend>
      <label for="chain-cfb">
          <input id="chain-cfb" name="chain" type="radio" />CFB
      </label>
      <label for="chain-cbc">
          <input id="chain-cbc" name="chain" type="radio" />CBC
      </label>
  </fieldset>               
</form>

<hr />
<p style="padding-top: 1em;">Some text underneath</p>   
</body> 
</html>
```

... and here is the content of demo.css...

```
fieldset
{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 17em;
    margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
    padding: 0 1em 1em 1em;
}

fieldset.radio input
{
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}

input
{
    display: block;
    width: 15em;
}

label
{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

label.first
{
    padding-top: 1em;
}
```

The way I read it, should be getting the desired result with this code. But I am not. Here is what renders instead ....

[image: Actual rending of HTML]

**What changes do I need to make to my html/css in order to get the stated desired result?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way without clearing is:

```
form { overflow: hidden; }
```

I usually create a class called `floatbox` and use this on every container which contains floating elements

```
.floatbox { overflow: hidden; }
```

the matching html then is

```
<form class="floatbox" action="">
    <fieldset><p>I'm floating</p></fieldset>
    <fieldset><p>me too</p></fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know you could do that!

Answer (score 2):

you need to make the `<hr />` element clear the floats. `hr { clear: left; }`

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
hr {
    clear: left;
}
```

to your style sheet to clear your floats.

Comment: Super quick answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ole' dummy clearing element trick:

```
<form action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Field set A</legend>
    <label for="password">Password
      <input id="password" name="password" type="text" value="my password" />
    </label>            
  </fieldset>               
  <fieldset class="radio">
    <legend>Chaining mode</legend>
      <label for="chain-cfb">
          <input id="chain-cfb" name="chain" type="radio" />CFB
      </label>
      <label for="chain-cbc">
          <input id="chain-cbc" name="chain" type="radio" />CBC
      </label>
  </fieldset> 
  <div style="clear:both"> </div>      
</form>
```

This ensures your form actually occupies as much space as the elements inside it.

The problem with simply clearing the `hr` is that the form has zero width and height, which could be problematic if you're applying styling to the form as well.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks. I don't actually know which of these answers is technically the best, so I will try them all out.